# Stopping JUnit suite if particular test fails

Tags: java, junit

I have a JUnit test suite in the form:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses( { xx.class, yy.cass })

public class AllTests {

public static Test suite() {
    TestSuite suite = new TestSuite(AllTests.class.getName());
    //$JUnit-BEGIN$

    //$JUnit-END$
    return suite;
}
}
```

This then calls vanilla tests like this:

```
public class xxx {

@Test
public void test () throws {
    ...
```

I have a situation where I'd like to stop the rest of the test suite running if there's an error or fail in the first test. But errors / fails in the others are ok and the suite should complete as many other tests as it can. Basically the first test failing would indicate it isn't safe to run the rest.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What's wrong with calling `System.exit()`?

Comment: How would I programmatically check if an assertion has failed?

Comment: Ok, I see I could catch AssertionError in the first test and then call System.exit(), but then the JUnit test won't pass or fail, just stop running. Seems like there should be a more elegant way.

Comment: Re: a more elegant way, I don't believe JUnit provides this functionality out of the box.  It can lead to coupling between tests.  Ideally your tests should run independent of one another and not be affected by other failures.  If you insist, then Hiro2k's suggestion is best.

Comment: Yeah I didn't want to get into the whole debate but if you did want a more elegant way then you'd have to find a way to decouple your tests from the order in which they run.

Comment: Thanks Hiro2k, after looking at the other options this seemed like the easiest to handle. I've written up precisely what I did in a new answer.

Comment: assertion and system.exit won't go together.  
Ideal soultion should be, 
@Rule
 public ErrorCollector collector = new ErrorCollector();

Comment: if you are using cucumber and configured your Hook's class, using System.exit(0) or 1 it does not go to after and before methods, in some cases those methods handle killing instances and finishing reports.

Answer (score 20):

First you need junit RunListener:

```
import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;
import org.junit.runner.notification.RunListener;
import org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier;

public class FailureListener extends RunListener {

    private RunNotifier runNotifier;

    public FailureListener(RunNotifier runNotifier) {
        super();
        this.runNotifier=runNotifier;
    }

    @Override
    public void testFailure(Failure failure) throws Exception {
        super.testFailure(failure);
        this.runNotifier.pleaseStop();
    }
}
```

Then prepare a suite:

```
public class StopOnFailureSuite extends Suite {

    public StopOnFailureSuite(Class<?> klass, Class<?>[] suiteClasses) throws InitializationError {
        super(klass, suiteClasses);
    }

    public StopOnFailureSuite(Class<?> klass) throws InitializationError {
        super(klass, klass.getAnnotation(SuiteClasses.class).value());
    }

    @Override
    public void run(RunNotifier runNotifier) {
        runNotifier.addListener(new FailureListener(runNotifier));
        super.run(runNotifier);
    }
}
```

And run your suite:

```
@RunWith(StopOnFailureSuite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
    FirstTestClass.class,
    SecondTestClass.class,
    ...
})
```

Comment: To implement what the question ask, `FailureListener` should not stop test on any failure. It might be better to filter the failure type and only stop tests on specific error. eg, creating your own `Exception` class and throw that in your `FirstTestClass`. Then use `failure.getException()` to determine whether to stop the test.

Comment: This is absolutely perfect for what I was looking for. Instead of a particular error, I wanted the tests to stop if they exceed more than 30% failure, and I was using Cucumber BDD. I merely had to override the run function and add the listener

Answer (score 5):

If it's **first** test then consider moving its validation to @BeforeClass and throw exception if it fails. Then only @AfterClass method would run in case of this exception.

Of course, that way you lack all the fixture artifacts created in test setup method(s).

Answer (score 4):

Like your answer but using `@Before` in an integration test, I did something like this:

```
public class FooTest {

   private static boolean bar;

   @BeforeClass
   public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
         bar = false;
   }

   @Before
   public void setUp() throws Exception {
         assertTrue(bar);
   }

   @Test
   public void test() {
         System.out.println("something");
         assertTrue(true);
   }

   @Test
   public void test1() {
         System.out.println("Something2");
         assertTrue(true);
   }
}
```

Regards!

Comment: I substituted `assumeTrue()` for your `assertTrue()`.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the answer from Hiro2k (thanks!) I've used the following solution. It's a bit of a hack but it works.

The test which can prevent other tests running goes at the top of the @Suite.SuiteClasses list. That test then has the following:

```
private static boolean shouldStopRestOfSuite = false;

    @Test
    public void test () throws Throwable {
    try {
            ... run some test code...
    }
    catch (Throwable e) {
        shouldStopRestOfSuite = true;
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Note the above does need to catch Throwable (not exception) so it catches assertion errors. It also re-throws the error so it's logged by JUnit for analysis.

Then there's another test method:

```
@Test
public void testKillIfNeeded () throws Exception {
    if (!shouldStopRestOfSuite) {
        return;
    }

    System.out.println ("Test suite killed due to dangerous error / failure");
    System.exit(1);
}
```

The above is run second and will kill the JUnit process.

Using this method the JUnit test won't end on fail / error if there's an issue but the fail / error is logged for analysis by JUnit and no further tests will run.

Not too pretty but it does the job :)

Comment: This can be made less clunky with something like  @Before
    public void beforeEachTest() {
        assertFalse("Testing has been aborted.",shouldStopRestOfSuite);}

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you should catch an error and check the same before you run the 2nd test.

```
@Rule
public ErrorCollector collector = new ErrorCollector();
```

**1. Add Error.**

```
collector.addError(new Throwable("first thing went wrong"));
```

**2. Check before the dependent run**.

```
collector.checkThat(getResult(), not(containsString("ERROR!")));
```

Reference - [ErrorCollector](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/ErrorCollector.html)

Answer (score 2):

I find it troubling that this functionality is so tedious to implement in such a mature library.  If you're using JUnit 5 / Jupiter you can use an extension called **JUnit Pioneer** (https://junit-pioneer.org).

With JUnit Pioneer you can simply add a [`@DisableIfTestFails`](https://junit-pioneer.org/docs/disable-if-test-fails/) annotation to your test class to make all tests stop when one fails.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running tests using ant?

You could write  a custom test listener. You can set this in ant http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html ( enableTestListenerEvents).

Comment: Although that is an option - I'm generally not using Ant (using Run As > JUnit Test in Eclipse).

Comment: How would you create that "custom test listener"?
I get the ant part with haltonfailure="true", but inside a Suite it does not stop if one of Suite's test fails. What "custom test listener" is able to do?