# How to break integration test when Spring context initializaiton fails?

Tags: spring, junit, integration-testing

All my tests share the same Spring configuration. It works effectively because context is started once and reused. Whole test suite completes in short time.

The problem is when Spring configuration is broken. In such case first test fails with

> IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

and each next test the same. It last long, because for each test context is started and failed.

Usually I am satisfied when testing process is continued after failure. But in this case I prefer to stop testing process - if context is not started once, it will never start successfully.

Is is possible to break test process in such case in JUnit 4/5?

Answer (score 0):

JUnit 4 has option to request stop tests, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/31397394/2365727
But using it is a bit difficult.

JUnit 5 seems do not have equivalent